# Teaching myself JavaScript: Table Editor

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, css

I am trying to teach myself JavaScript. I've read some online tutorials and watched some Douglas Crockford videos and decided to dive right in.

I made a little table editor in JavaScript: there's been quite a bit of fighting with the DOM but I think I've mostly figured this out.

Am I on the right track? Any comments on what I could do better or have misconceptions about?

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head><title>Learning JS</title><style>
    div.body { padding-top: 30px; padding-left: 10%; }
    table { border-collapse:collapse; }
    td { border-top: 2px solid #ddd; padding: 0 16px; }
    td:focus { outline-style: none; box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 4px #87CEEB }
</style>
</head>
<body><div class=body>
<table><tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Value</th>
     <th>Col3</th>
    <th>Col4</th>
    <th>Col5</th>
</tr><tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Testing, testing, 123</td>
    <td>Another Column</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>end</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>This Time</td>
    <td>nothing else</td>
    <td>testing some more</td>
    <td></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>This other time</td>
    <td>nothing more</td>
    <td>test this</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<script src=te.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```js
"use strict";
window.onload = function() {
    var firstColumn;
    var lastColumn;
    {
        let tables=document.getElementsByTagName("table");
        var width=tables[0].rows[0].cells.length;
        let td=document.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (let i=0,len=td[0].parentNode.cells.length;i<len;++i) {
            if (firstColumn===undefined) firstColumn=i;
            lastColumn=i;
        }
        for (let i = 0;i < td.length; ++i) {
            td[i].onkeydown = kbhandle;
            if (!td[i].className) td[i].setAttribute("contentEditable", true);
        }
    }
    var tabpos=1;
    function kbhandle(e) {
        switch (e.which) {
            case 9:
                if (tabpos>this.cellIndex) tabpos=this.cellIndex;
                break;
            case 13:
                if (e.shiftKey || e.altKey || e.ctrlKey) break;
                return function(that) {
                    let row=that.parentNode;
                    if (row.rowIndex < row.parentNode.rows.length-1) row.nextSibling.cells[tabpos].focus();
                    return false;
                } (this);
            case 37:    //Left Arrow
                return function(that,sel) {
                    if (e.altKey || (!sel.anchorOffset && (sel.focusNode.tagName==='TD' || sel.focusNode.previousSibling === null))) {
                        if (that.cellIndex > firstColumn) {
                            tabpos=that.cellIndex-1;
                            that.parentNode.cells[tabpos].focus();
                            if (sel.rangeCount) {
                                let node;
                                let range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                                if (node = that.parentNode.cells[that.cellIndex-1].lastChild) {
                                    range.setStart(node,node.length);
                                    range.setEnd(node,node.length);
                                    sel.removeAllRanges();  //needed for Webkit
                                    sel.addRange(range);    //needed for Webkit
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                } (this,window.getSelection());
            case 38:    //Up Arrow
                return function(that,sel) {
                    if (e. ctrlKey || e.altKey || (!sel.anchorOffset && (sel.focusNode.tagName==='TD' || sel.focusNode.previousSibling === null))) {
                        tabpos=that.cellIndex;
                        that.parentNode.previousSibling.cells[that.cellIndex].focus();
                        if (sel.rangeCount) {
                            let node;
                            let range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                            if ((node = that.parentNode.previousSibling.cells[that.cellIndex].lastChild) && node.parentElement.tagName === 'TD') {
                                range.setStart(node,node.length);
                                range.setEnd(node,node.length);
                                sel.removeAllRanges();  //needed for Webkit
                                sel.addRange(range);    //needed for Webkit
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                } (this,window.getSelection());
            case 39:    //Right Arrow
                return function(that,sel) {
                    let len=sel.focusNode.textContent.length;
                    if (that.cellIndex<lastColumn && (e.altKey || !len || (len === sel.anchorOffset && sel.focusNode.nextSibling === null))) {
                        tabpos=that.cellIndex+1;
                        that.parentNode.cells[that.cellIndex+1].focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                } (this,window.getSelection());
            case 40:    //Down Arrow
                return function(that,sel) {
                    let len=sel.focusNode.textContent.length;
                    if (e. ctrlKey || e.altKey || !len || (len === sel.anchorOffset && sel.focusNode.nextSibling === null)) {
                        let row=that.parentNode;
                        tabpos=that.cellIndex;
                        if (row.rowIndex < row.parentNode.rows.length-1) row.nextSibling.cells[that.cellIndex].focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                } (this,window.getSelection());
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've embedded your code into a Code Snippet below, so anyone can easily see your code running. I've also put it into a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tmirkovic/qupkx73w/4/) so that it can be easily edited.

```js
"use strict";

var firstColumn;
var lastColumn; {
  let tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
  var width = tables[0].rows[0].cells.length;
  let td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (let i = 0, len = td[0].parentNode.cells.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (firstColumn === undefined) firstColumn = i;
    lastColumn = i;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < td.length; ++i) {
    td[i].onkeydown = kbhandle;
    if (!td[i].className) td[i].setAttribute("contentEditable", true);
  }
}
var tabpos = 1;

function kbhandle(e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    case 9:
      if (tabpos > this.cellIndex) tabpos = this.cellIndex;
      break;
    case 13:
      if (e.shiftKey || e.altKey || e.ctrlKey) break;
      return function(that) {
        let row = that.parentNode;
        if (row.rowIndex < row.parentNode.rows.length - 1) row.nextSibling.cells[tabpos].focus();
        return false;
      }(this);
    case 37: //Left Arrow
      return function(that, sel) {
        if (e.altKey || (!sel.anchorOffset && (sel.focusNode.tagName === 'TD' || sel.focusNode.previousSibling === null))) {
          if (that.cellIndex > firstColumn) {
            tabpos = that.cellIndex - 1;
            that.parentNode.cells[tabpos].focus();
            if (sel.rangeCount) {
              let node;
              let range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
              if (node = that.parentNode.cells[that.cellIndex - 1].lastChild) {
                range.setStart(node, node.length);
                range.setEnd(node, node.length);
                sel.removeAllRanges(); //needed for Webkit
                sel.addRange(range); //needed for Webkit
              }
            }
          }
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }(this, window.getSelection());
    case 38: //Up Arrow
      return function(that, sel) {
        if (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey || (!sel.anchorOffset && (sel.focusNode.tagName === 'TD' || sel.focusNode.previousSibling === null))) {
          tabpos = that.cellIndex;
          that.parentNode.previousSibling.cells[that.cellIndex].focus();
          if (sel.rangeCount) {
            let node;
            let range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            if ((node = that.parentNode.previousSibling.cells[that.cellIndex].lastChild) && node.parentElement.tagName === 'TD') {
              range.setStart(node, node.length);
              range.setEnd(node, node.length);
              sel.removeAllRanges(); //needed for Webkit
              sel.addRange(range); //needed for Webkit
            }
          }
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }(this, window.getSelection());
    case 39: //Right Arrow
      return function(that, sel) {
        let len = sel.focusNode.textContent.length;
        if (that.cellIndex < lastColumn && (e.altKey || !len || (len === sel.anchorOffset && sel.focusNode.nextSibling === null))) {
          tabpos = that.cellIndex + 1;
          that.parentNode.cells[that.cellIndex + 1].focus();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }(this, window.getSelection());
    case 40: //Down Arrow
      return function(that, sel) {
        let len = sel.focusNode.textContent.length;
        if (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey || !len || (len === sel.anchorOffset && sel.focusNode.nextSibling === null)) {
          let row = that.parentNode;
          tabpos = that.cellIndex;
          if (row.rowIndex < row.parentNode.rows.length - 1) row.nextSibling.cells[that.cellIndex].focus();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }(this, window.getSelection());
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
div.body {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 10%;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border-top: 2px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0 16px;
}

td:focus {
  outline-style: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 4px #87CEEB
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Learning JS</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class=body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Col3</th>
        <th>Col4</th>
        <th>Col5</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Testing, testing, 123</td>
        <td>Another Column</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>end</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>This Time</td>
        <td>nothing else</td>
        <td>testing some more</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>This other time</td>
        <td>nothing more</td>
        <td>test this</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Lets start with the first chunk of code:

```
var firstColumn;
var lastColumn;
{
    let tables=document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    var width=tables[0].rows[0].cells.length;
    let td=document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (let i=0,len=td[0].parentNode.cells.length;i<len;++i) {
        if (firstColumn===undefined) firstColumn=i;
        lastColumn=i;
    }
    for (let i = 0;i < td.length; ++i) {
        td[i].onkeydown = kbhandle;
        if (!td[i].className) td[i].setAttribute("contentEditable", true);
    }
}
```

The extra block statement makes the code slightly harder to read. It's important to remember that `tables` and `td` will not be accessible outside the block, but `width` will. That might be the intended behavior here, but using extra blocks like this could easily get you trouble.

The `width` variable is never used after being set.

It would seem like `firstColumn` is always set to 0 no matter what. Setting it with an if statement during the for loop is unnecessary. You can just set it to 0 when you initialize it.

In fact that whole first for loop is unnecessary, since you can just set last column to `td[0].parentNode.cells.length -1`